# Nuxt.js при асинхронных запросах постоянно выкидывает на страницу ошибки

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Создал первое приложение на Nuxt.js + Laravel(REST).
При запросах через Axios, если возвращается ответ с ошибкой, например ошибка валидации формы на бекенде, то появляется страница ошибки
[image: Страница ошибки Nuxt]

Из-за этого невозможно обрабатывать ошибки. Но при запуске приложения не в develop режиме (npm run buid => npm run start) такого поведения нет. Подскажите как избавится от такого поведения в режиме develop (npm run dev)?
Пример запроса

```
async register() {
  await this.$axios.post('/auth/register', this.form);

  this.$auth.login({data: this.form});

  this.$router.push({name: 'index'});
},
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример использования axios'а

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка, которая на скрине, появляется, если вы не обрабатываете ошибку axios'a

В случае, с async & await необходимо использовать try..catch

Например

```js
async register () { 
  try {
    await this.$axios.post('/auth/register', this.form); 

    await this.$auth.login({data: this.form}); 

    this.$router.push({name: 'index'}); 
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO обработка ошибки
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```